# Configuring 3 identical Windows 7 machines

Tags: windows-7, installation, deployment

I ordered 3 three identical machines with Windows 7 Pro pre-installed. Now I need to install identical software on each of them and apply identical Windows configuration to each of them.

I know there are various tools which help you streamline this process (some discussed in [Deploying identical setup Windows over multiple computers](https://superuser.com/questions/356695)).

The question is whether it's worth the effort for only 3 PCs as I've never used any of those tools. Is learning and configuring the tools gonna cost more (time-wise) than what I'd save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`sysprep`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721973%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) utility is designed to solve your problem. Running `sysprep` before you image will clear all the unique ID's and prepare it for imaging.

1. Set one computer up to your preferences.
2. Prepare the system with the command `sysprep /generalize`. The sysprep utility should be located in `C:\Windows\system32\sysprep\sysprep.exe`. Open `cmd.exe` and `cd` to that directory first.
3. Shutdown the computer.
4. Boot your preferred disk-imaging software (I recommend [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) if you need something free) and image the drive. Do your best to prevent the computer from booting into Windows before you image it.
5. Deploy the image on the other computers.
6. Boot each computer and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Why not set 1 up and then use something like Norton Ghost  (or possible free alternatives) to make an image of the hard disk.  Then clone the other machines from this image.  If the machines are identical this should work well and you have an image you can revert back to if you wish.

Comment: All machines came with Windows pre-installed. Not only would I wipe that installation by applying the image it'd also clone the Windows license (key) and the internal ID. This will cause problems if the machines connect to the Internet and Microsoft finds out I'm running the same license on three machines I guess.

Comment: On Dell machines, you generally don't need to input the key as there is some sort of hardward chip that notifies it as  Dell machine.  Microsoft don't mind as long as you have the licences.  This is how large companies do it so its all perfectly legal as long as you have the licences.