# Where can I store driver files so that Windows sees them when it 'searches automatically' for them?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, drivers, imaging

I am in the process of creating a few generic images and I have downloaded all the drivers for all the models of machines we use here. I can extract these drivers to any location but I am not sure where Windows looks when it is searching for drivers. Is there a driver store somewhere in Windows that it searches through?

These images will be created for: Windows XP, Windows 7 x86/x64

Are the locations different between Windows XP and Windows 7? Are they different if the OS is x64 based? I know Windows likes to differentiate 32/64bit software all over the place, not sure if they do the same with driver stores.

Comment: See: [What is sysprep? How is it useful?](http://superuser.com/questions/68697/what-is-sysprep-how-is-it-useful)

Comment: That's not automatically at all...

Comment: @techie007 what does sysprep have to do with pulling in drivers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows XP tends to dump things in C:\Windows\System32\drivers, i've certainly copied drivers there in the past to automate detection (usually with USB devices). Unsure about your other points with x86 and x64 though, although certainly windows will detect and install what's needed - **not** what you put in its system folders :)

Windows 7 has the same drivers folder... But i've not tried/needed to copy files there (yet)...

Comment: Thanks! Tried and tested in Windows 7? :)