# How to programmatically change windows data?

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, windows-pe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Sysprep?  How is it useful?](https://superuser.com/questions/68697/what-is-sysprep-how-is-it-useful)

I have a WMI image to load a preload and preconfigured image of windows. We use Windows PE in a boot USB to load this and autoformat the HDD.

Everything works as we expected, however, we need to add the machine to a domain and change some information of the machine (such as the name, company, etc). We can make it using Configuration Manager, but (as every windows software) some times it fails, or we have to format the PC in order to register it to CM and then format it, again, with the image we've configured. In order to avoid this, we install all the images in one 32GB USB pendrive, so from there we can install everything.

How can I change the domain of the computer and add all this information in the same way CM do it?

***Ps. I have found how to change the machine name with a batch script, but we need to change more information than just the name:***

```
SET /P PCNAME=Please enter your name: 
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName /v ComputerName /t REG_SZ /d %PCNAME% /f
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName\ /v ComputerName /t REG_SZ /d %PCNAME% /f
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\ /v Hostname /t REG_SZ /d %PCNAME% /f
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\ /v "NV Hostname" /t REG_SZ /d %PCNAME% /f
```

**EDIT**

I have this in my Configuration Manager:

```
    <step type="SMS_TaskSequence_ApplyNetworkSettingsAction" name="Apply Network Settings" description="Actions to configure network settings" runIn="WinPEandFullOS" successCodeList="0">
      <action>osdnetsettings.exe configure</action>
      <defaultVarList>
        <variable name="OSDDomainName" property="DomainName">something.domain.org</variable>
        <variable name="OSDDomainOUName" property="DomainOUName">LDAP://OU=Transition PCs,OU=Clients,OU=MEX,DC=something,DC=domain,DC=org</variable>
        <variable name="OSDJoinPassword" property="DomainPassword">
        </variable>
        <variable name="OSDJoinAccount" property="DomainUsername">something\user</variable>
        <variable name="OSDEnableTCPIPFiltering" property="EnableTCPIPFiltering" hidden="true">false</variable>
        <variable name="OSDNetworkJoinType" property="NetworkJoinType">0</variable>
        <variable name="OSDAdapterCount" property="NumAdapters" hidden="true">0</variable>
      </defaultVarList>
    </step>
```

And this is all the information I need to change after installing the wim. It make use of osdnetsettings.exe, but this program exists only within CM...