# Automate new computer set up?

Tags: windows, windows-installation

I set up new computers for customers with Windows 7, Office 2013, other programs, update everything, etc.

The process is long and tedious.

Is there any way to automate all of this into as little amount of steps as possible?

The only thing that is quick and easy is installation of typical programs a user would use using Ninite. But updating windows, installing Office, etc, takes a while.

Comment: That's what [SysPrep](http://superuser.com/questions/68697/what-is-sysprep-how-is-it-useful) is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a cloning software such as Macrium Reflect (which has a free version) might be worthwhile.

Though cloning software is most valuable when the systems are identical, in your case you could set up a single device, install software, and run updates on it- then make a backup of it.

Each time you need to set up a new computer you could then copy the image to them and then make small adjustments such as adding correct drivers and proper licensing information for Windows/Office.

This would at least cut down the time you spent configuring each new system.

(caveat: I haven't used Macrium for this purpose, I use Windows Deployment Services, which I am assuming you don't have access to.)