# Windows xp prodcut key

Tags: windows, windows-xp, product-key, ghost

I am trying to remove a product key from windows XP when creating a ghost (each pc can then add there own PK for that hardware) but I am coming against some problems. I have tried the following.

Deleted wpadbl and wpa.bak from system32 folder (in some cases the .exe)
Changed oobetimer in the registry (even deleted it)
I have restarted the PC and I get a message to say Windows could not verify the status of the activation and asks me to activate again.

I go through the process of the wizard asking to activate and register, but it passes the part where you should enter your product key and says it has been successfully activated. This of course leads me to think the key hasn't been deleted.

I must be missing a step, anybody come across this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Do it properly, [use Sysprep](http://superuser.com/questions/68697/what-is-sysprep-how-is-it-useful).

Comment: Aside from answering this question, you do know that windows XP is expired, right? Microsoft does not release security updates for Windows XP for quite a while now, which means hackers are more and more likely to be able to breach security. When doing something like this question, it may be better to look for alternative OS's, preferably newer versions such as Windows 7 or 8.1

Comment: Yes I am aware, but currently we are unable to move to a different OS we are phasing them out, but the time is out of my hands. Thanks

Comment: i don't know much about the activation aspect but there is a program to change the product key https://www.magicaljellybean.com/beta/  "Change Windows key option should be available for Windows XP & 2003. "  and http://www.technize.info/how-to-change-windows-xp-product-key/