# Modify Windows Installation by custom bat file

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, windows-installation

How can I with no usage of 3rd party tool modify Windows Installation by packing custom bat file into Windows 10 installer? I expect that installer start it after installation with privileges that bat will able to modify registry for example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a master image and then use [Sysprep](https://superuser.com/questions/68697/what-is-sysprep-how-is-it-useful) to setup the image for copying by creating an unattended answer file (`unattend.xml`), and to include your custom batch file.

Specifically, look into `Setupcomplete.cmd` usage:

[Add a Custom Script to Windows Setup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898472(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Windows Setup scripts: Setupcomplete.cmd and ErrorHandler.cmd are
>   custom scripts that run during or after the Windows Setup process.
>   They can be used to install applications or run other tasks by using
>   cscript/wscript scripts.

...

> 1. After Windows is installed but before the logon screen appears, Windows Setup searches for the `SetupComplete.cmd` file in the
>      `%WINDIR%\Setup\Scripts\` directory.
> 2. If a `SetupComplete.cmd` file is found, Windows Setup runs the script. Windows Setup logs the action in the
>      `C:\Windows\Panther\UnattendGC\Setupact.log` file.